# Debugging silverlight application problem

Tags: silverlight, debugging

My VS2010 doesn't stop at breakpoints inside of silverlight application. It appears that no symbols for it have been loaded during debugging. When I hover over the break point it says "The braekpoint will not currently be hit, no symbols have been loaded".

I have tried all of possible solutions offered by google and have no success. The problem occurs even when I create brand new silverlight app hosted by an ASP .NET web project. All of my project configuration looks fine - silverlight debugging is enabled in the Web project.

I am using silverlight 4.
here a [link to the sample project](https://www.wetransfer.com/dl.php?code=p9G7r4UM&hash=768c9a94a342f8949245d1403188bd6bb61cbe017084b36536c56a688de8d8b0727c3b6fd7fa2) created out from the tepmlate.

Any thoughts ?

P.S I just tried to reinstall VS2010 and the problem still exists.

EDIT: I just tested the same project on another machine and it stops at the break point it seams that the problem is somewhere in the configuration of VS or silverlight.

with Matt Dotson's help I managed to attach the debugger manually. However this solution is not good enough for daily use.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Depending on my experience in Silverlight following these steps keep your project debug-gable.

Condition 1>

Firstly we need to be ensure that in Web Project's properties there is a Web section, as you see below Silverlight checkbox must be checked.

[image]

Condition 2>
Follow In Menu Debug => Attach Debugger>

Visual Studio sometimes can't attach debugging platform you need to lead the way :) . By this way you may debug other platforms,(also you may debug your product platform but pdb files must be sync and don't forget you may suspend your product platform using this).

[image]

Condition 3> Your default web browser may be Firefox,Chrome or other than IE.By Visual Studio default try to attach to IE. But when you run VS calls default browser,so you need to have a manual attachment in Condition 2 or set your default browser by right clicking on default page > Browse with .

[image]

Condition 4> There is xap file generally located in web project\ClientBin directory. Sometimes after build operations this file can't be replaced and your ProjectDll and your Project PDB files not be sync. This cause wrong line match while debugging or can't find a debugging file attached caution. I strongly suggest delete all generated files in Bus project and delete Clientbin\ProjectName.xap file. After rebuild all it must be ok!

[image]

Hope helps.

Answer (score 6):

What broswer are you using? You need to be using Internet Explorer to debug silverlight projects.

Comment: @donal its not true at all I use firefox to debug Sl projects.

Comment: @Malcolm: With the new Firefox 3.6.4 and above i´m not able to debug any silverlight project. This version hosts silverlight in a special container for execution.

Comment: @Jehof didn't knew about that. Tx for the info. As i am still on Firefox 3.5

Comment: @Jehof there's a workaround for it here :
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/188434.aspx

Comment: I have successfully debugged using FF so far. I have that debugging problem also with IE and Chrome.

Comment: the key is to set IE as default browser and not copy/past the link, just let VS open the browser

Answer (score 4):

I have had a similar frustrating experience with this but in my case the solution was very simple. It seems that somehow, and I really have no idea how, the debugger option for Silverlight had become unchecked in the properties on the hosting ASP.NET project.

I just assumed that as I had been previously debugging, this option was set and I didn't bother to make sure that this was this case. Just goes to show that one should always check the basics first; if I had done that it would have saved me some time.

To check this in VS2010, right-click on the project and select properties, change to the Web tab and check the Silverlight option at the bottom of the page, in the debuggers section.

Answer (score 3):

- Also see the debugger to a silverlight process 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838267(VS.95).aspx

If that doesn't work, then

- reset iis (if you are debugging in that)
- delete temporary asp.net files (%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files)
- clean and rebuild your solution

Comment: I have done all of that - it doesn't help.
I'm using the development server of the VS so I don't have IIS to reset.

Comment: did you attach to the process running silverlight, or just hit F5?

Comment: Try CTRL+ALT+P and attaching to the IE process that has SL in it.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+P work - 10x a lot. But that is no good enough solution for daily use.

Answer (score 2):

The resolution came after 2 days of headbanging. It appears that the [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/188434.aspx) which Malcolm gave covers exactly my problem but my I was narrow-minded enough not to pay it enough attention because when I run the debugger as long with the app my default browser was FF. So I thought that after the FF starts I can load the page from IE or Chrome.

Actually the problem is that the debugger cannot be attached to the silverlight project because of the FF. And when I load the app from IE or Chrome the debugger dis still not attached.

Thanks to everyone that tried to help.

Comment: Thanks, it worked out for me. Additionally I had to reboot Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple project, Rebuild the project separately that you want break point. Its work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try also picking internet explorer from browser list menu as your browser