# "No symbols have been loaded" - Silverlight project cannot find pdb files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, iis-express

I've got a web project that runs a Silverlight app. Due to the massive build times I am trying to use "Attach to Process" instead of running in debug in Visual Studio.

When I build the full solution I can attach fine, but when I make a change and build the changed project I get "The breakpoint will not be currently hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

If I check the modules window and look at the the offending project I see "Cannot find or open the PDB file". I check the load information and it says "C:\Source\Project\Web\bin\myProject.pdb: PDB does not match image.: PDB does not match image."

After the build of the single project the following files are updated:
C:\Source\Project\Web\bin\myProjectName.pdb
C:\Source\Project\Web\bin\myProjectName.dll
C:\Source\Project\Web\ClientBin\myProjectName.xap
C:\Source\Project\bin\Debug\myProjectName.pdb
C:\Source\Project\bin\Debug\myProjectName.dll
C:\Source\Project\bin\Debug\myProjectName.xap
C:\Source\Project\myProjectName\obj\Debug\myProjectName.pdb
C:\Source\Project\myProjectName\obj\Debug\myProjectName.dll
C:\Source\Project\myProjectName\bin\Debug\myProjectName.pdb
C:\Source\Project\myProjectName\bin\Debug\myProjectName.dll

So everything looks ok. The same files are updated if I do a full rebuild.

I've tried copying the contents of the build folder into the Web bin folder. I've tried setting Symbols file locations for all of the above folders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have found that when debugging Silverlight projects, I have to make sure the project launches using the IE browser.  I'm not sure if this is your problem, because it could be anything - just a thought though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure C:\Source\Project\Web\ClientBin\myProjectName.xap file is changing. Check FileLastWriteDate. And follow my previous post about this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12781653/413032

Hope helps.

Comment: The Xap appears to be updating.
I have it working (most of the time) now. I have added in symbols folders for all locations. I have 3 instances of Visual Studio:

1) Solution with only the web project, the initial startup silverlight project and the silverlight project that I'm currently working in.
2) Full Solution (all projects loaded( for client-side debugging
3) Full Solution (all project loaded) for server-side debugging.

Comment: If I make a change to the silverlight project I'm working on I DON'T build it in 2) as this fails to load the symbols. I switch to 1) and run without debugging ( I have to include the newly changed project though - otherwise the symbols are out of date).

Comment: I then attach in 2) to iexplore.exe and most of the time I can debug. Sometimes however, it is the other way around - I have to build in 2) and run without debugging in 1) to get the symbols to load. I can attach in 3) to iisexpress.exe if I want to debug the server side (this is the most reliable. I only build the server side items in this solution and the symbols are normally in-sync).

I wish I knew exactly what is happening during the build process so I could get things working 100% of the time...

Comment: Firstly you wrote down "3 instance of VS" so this may cause a problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/2524/413032 . As I see you are trying develop rapidly.New generation programming approaches producing many generated codes ,especially for UIs. These auto generations of your VS2010?'s makes your projects non-synchronized. I think this is worst side of plugin development you need to package your app. And as I experienced asp net development server lives for while then you sessions. Maybe you may use IIS instead of express.